# get-aduser filter by non english characters

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to get account SamAccountName from its description.This script works fine

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "description -like '*qwerty*'" | Select-Object SamAccountName
```

But if I change "qwerty" with cyrillic symbols, script does not return expected result. What should I do to be able to search with cyrillic symbols?

Answer (score 1):

In the background, the `-Filter` parameter value gets transformed to an LDAP filter.
According to [RFC 4515 Section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4515#section-3), you'll first need to UTF-8 encode your input string, and then escape non-ASCII characters using backslash (`\`)

Haven't been able to test it, but this should do the trick:

```
$CyrillicString = "Алексей"
$UTF8EncodedStr = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($CyrillicString)
$EscapedUTF8Str = $UTF8EncodedStr |ForEach-Object { "\{0:X2}" -f $( $_ -as [int16] ) }
Get-ADUser -Filter "name -like '$( -join $EscapedUTF8Str )'"
```

Comment: It seems like it will match ascii characters anyway, and the * can't be in utf8.